# Deployment simple java dns(socket udp) in reality

Tags: java, dns

I have build a simple DNS server via socket java. Its function is to receive a request(domain) and search in database and provide response to an IP address of a client, on the command line. I have send message(string) from client <-> server successfully. The problem here is I want to do this when a user sets up my DNS and when they access the address to internet via browser, my DNS return an IP and browser redirects to this IP. Can you help me?

Comment: i have build an dns server same in here http://javabasicstudy.blogspot.com/2011/07/program-for-domain-name-system-dns_27.html
I want when the user installs my dns, they visit facebook. com on web browser,  my dns returns 173.252.91.4 and web browser redirect to this ip. thank @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Then the user needs to set their local system dns to the machine where they have installed your dns. However, unless you've implemented more of dns then you have said; it will likely "break" their internet. Further, you should know that facebook uses more than one domain name.

Comment: the problem here is i don't know how to ip response can used by browser. My dns used in special case.  can you suggest me library in java support this problem?.